# Can anyone provide the sloka, which narrates what Saraswati ji said in Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, saraswati

When gods approached Saraswati ji to change the mind of Manthara, she said one shlok (my grandmother told me long ago).

I don't remember what she said.  If someone could tell me what the sloka was, as I couldn't find it on internet.

Comment: The other question or answer there under does not contain reference to the sloka that OP is interested in.  So it may not be a duplicate one. @sv.

Comment: Yes, but if you go by the title it's a duplicate. @srimannarayanakv

Answer (score 0):

Saraswati's intervention in changing the mind of Manthara does not find place in Valmiki's Ramayana.  It is from Sri Tulasi Das's Ramacharita Manas.

As the sloka concerned could not be copied properly, I am providing a [link to that sloka-3](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n377/mode/2up) below Doha-11 (page 379).

> u°ca nivåsu nici karatµuti, dekhi na sakahiÚ  paråi bibhµuti.
>
> ågila  kåju bicåri bahori, karihahiÚ cåha kusala kabi mori

The [meaning of the sloka](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n379/mode/2up) is as follows (Page 380).

> She said to herself, "Though their abode is on high, their doings are
>   mean; they cannot see others prosperity."